# Display values greater than a specific number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report in Excel which lists clients and the amount of hours that we work on them.

I want to create a separate sheet within this workbook that pulls the clients that we work on over 40 hours, through VBA.

For example basic version of my report looks like this in Sheet 1

**Client------Client ID---Hours**

Client 1------1947--------30

Client 2------6465--------46

Client 3------8787--------20

Client 4------7878--------15

Client 5------4873--------48

I want my new sheet to display

**Client------Client ID---Hours**

Client 2------6465--------46

Client 5------4873--------48

I am wondering if it is a while loop but wouldn't it break as soon as it finds the first value greater than 40 then it wouldn't continue to the next set of values?

Comment: Take a look at [pivot tables](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) instead of VBA.  I think you'll find it more flexible and achieves the same result.

Comment: You could read the range into a Collection with logic to filter the ones that you don't want and have a method that puts that Collection  into another sheet. The downside of this is that you will be holding  your information in memory. About how many clients are we talking about?

Comment: Well the thing is for every client there are 2 or 3 workers that work on that client.  So for example there is Client 1 has a total of lets say 43 hours.  Worker A did 20hours Worker B did 10 Hours and Worker C did the remaining 13 hours for a combined worked hours of 43 hours.  It is a lot of clients...we are talking about 300 clients.  Thats not huge but the faster I can separate the ones with over 40 hours the easier.  On one sheet I have the clients with each worker hours...then I have one sheet that just shows me the total hours for each client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recorded a quick macro to get the code for the filter criteria and then used `Copy Destination:=` .  Recording macros and reviewing them is a great way to start learning some VBA

```
Sub Shorty()

    Cells.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">40", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

You can find the documentation for the Copy Method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx)